# How can I pass a next token and last sync value to AWS AppSync?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync, dynamodb-queries

I am using a sync query like below.

```
query MyQuery {
  syncObjects(limit: 10, nextToken: "123", lastSync: 1111) {
    items {
      _deleted
      id
    }
    startedAt
    nextToken
  }
}
```

If I have a nextToken from a previous call, I pass it along with my last sync value. It works without the next token, but when an next token is passed I get the following error...

```
Error: The supplied Item contains a null AttributeValue (Service: DynamoDb, Status Code: 400.
```

I have the same problem if I use the AppSync Console, so it is not anything in my project. So what do I do if I make a sync query and get back a next token?

Answer (score 0):

Typically when `The supplied Item contains a null AttributeValue` exception is thrown its because DynamoDB does not like empty string values: `""`.

Make sure the `NextToken` is not providing empty string values, if that fails you need to submit feedback to AWS.